# How to stop loading the webview in android

Tags: android, android-webview

I am worked on tab bar application, The webview is not properly loaded the onReceiveError() method will be called and displayed error description in a alert box. After displaying the alert box the webview is displayed as "WebPage not available" content same as in any browser. How can I display a empty white page after displaying alert box.?. The alert box is displayed in a overlapped way one after the after. How can I display the alert box to specific tab bar.?

Answer (score 1):

You could try `webView.clearView()` to display an empty white page. Here's the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#clearView%28%29).

Comment: how about the alertbox to the tab bar.

Comment: I don't understand the second part of the question. Please reformulate.

Comment: Hey! i did'nt ask the question!..He is saying that he's using a tabbed layout.. and if he calls an alertdialog from one place it gets called from the otehr place too

Comment: I am displaying the alert box, when network error will occurred. The alert box is displayed simultaneously in all the tab bars. How can I display alert box for tabs when error occurred in current tab bar.?

Comment: After using the webView.clearView(), the webpage not available will be shown.Any other suggestions please.

Comment: Are you using `TabActivity` or `Fragments` ?

Comment: I am using TabActivity. Still facing "Webpage not available" error in webview.

Answer (score 0):

Simple :

make your static html error page and put in assets folder , and after receiving error inside onReceiveError() you can load this static html page in web view with your custom message :